# Entity Framework - inspect foreach/update query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have the following query:

```
db.Context.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.abc == someAbc && x.zyx == someZyx)
    .ForEach(y =>
    {
        y.AuditId = newAuditId;
        y.TimeStamp = newTimestamp;
    });
```

I would like to get the actual SQL query out of the `ForEach` statement.

If I do just the following:

```
var selectQuery = db.Context.SomeTable
        .Where(x => x.abc == someAbc && x.zyx == someZyx);
```

I can get the following query from selectQuery variable:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[abc] AS [abc], 
    [Extent1].[zyx] AS [zyx] 
    --skipping some [Extent1]. statements for simplicity here
FROM 
    [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    ([Extent1].[abc] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[zyx] = @p__linq__1)
```

Which I can then run outside of Visual Studio, analyze the performance of it, etc.

How would I do this for the `ForEach` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` execute and fetch the data from your server. `ForEach` is not translated into SQL. It just execute the Linq To Entities you just wrote :

```
var selectQuery = db.Context.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.abc == someAbc && x.zyx == someZyx);
```

Which generate the SQL you worte in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, `ForEach` does *not* get translated into a SQL statement.  If you want to make those changes in .NET and save them back to the database, then you'll need to call [`SaveChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) to update the data source:

```
var items = db.Context.SomeTable
                      .Where(x => x.abc == someAbc && x.zyx == someZyx);

foreach(var item in items)
{
        item.AuditId = newAuditId;
        item.TimeStamp = newTimestamp;
}

db.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at setting this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx

I've used this in the past, but by the time you get the query it has already been executed.  This may or may not help you.

Comment: Is there an example on how to use this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to mention 'ToList()' before 'foreach'. you need an array or list to do the loop.

Here is my example,

```
public HomePageBannerModel GetBannerImage()
        {
            var banner = new HomePageBannerModel();
            _jBannerRepository.Table.Where(x => x.BannerType == BannerTypes.Home).ToList()
           .ForEach(y =>
           {
               switch (y.Size)
               {
                   case "M":
                       banner.Md = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(y.PictureId);
                       break;
                   case "S":
                       banner.Sm = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(y.PictureId);
                       break;
                   default:
                       banner.Lg = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(y.PictureId);
                       break;
               }
           });

            return banner;
        }
```